# Switch from Resharper 5 Intellisense to Visual Studio Intellisense using a command

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, resharper-5.0

Is it possible to go to `Resharper -> Options -> IntelliSense -> General` and switch from Resharper to Visual Studio using a command in Resharper 5?

I would like to benefit from the Razor Intellisense which comes with ASP.NET MVC 3 RC but Resharper makes it look buggy (take a look at [Scott's Tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/shanselman/statuses/2263219917819904)).

Comment: This makes me sad.  I'm a resharper user and tonight was supposed to be investigate Razor night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if is possible to to only turn ReSharper intellisense on and off. However, you can turn all of ReSharper on and off using a keyboard shortcut. On my computer it still takes a few seconds but it may be the best solution until the bug is fixed.

In **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Environment** -> **Keyboard** bind the **ReSharper_ToggleSuspended** command to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I already used this workaround. Unfortunately this is darn slow since I have 20+ projects in the solution. On a simple solution with only 2 - 3 projects it also works quickly. I guess I will be adding/editing views only in bulk ;) Hope they will fix the bug quickly (not after launching R# 6 :)